# module 'utils' has no attribute 'MetricLogger'

Tags: python, pytorch, module

I was following the tutorial online about fine-tuning a mask rcnn model using PyTorch documents. But I was somehow stuck with the import of the file.

Here's the thing. There are several help functions that was defined by PyTorch and was imported in the tutorial. However, when running this part of the code, it kept going error message.

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-cbedd53a614e> in <cell line: 61>()
     61 for epoch in range(num_epochs):
     62     # train for one epoch, printing every 10 iterations
---> 63     train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=10)
     64     # update the learning rate
     65     lr_scheduler.step()

/content/engine.py in train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq, scaler)

AttributeError: module 'utils' has no attribute 'MetricLogger'
```

Here is my code:

```
import myutils
from engine import train_one_epoch, evaluate


# train on the GPU or on the CPU, if a GPU is not available
device = torch.device('cuda') if torch.cuda.is_available() else torch.device('cpu')

# our dataset has two classes only - background and person
num_classes = 2
# use our dataset and defined transformations
dataset = PennFudanDataset('data/PennFudanPed', get_transform(train=True))
dataset_test = PennFudanDataset('data/PennFudanPed', get_transform(train=False))

# split the dataset in train and test set
indices = torch.randperm(len(dataset)).tolist()
dataset = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset, indices[:-50])
dataset_test = torch.utils.data.Subset(dataset_test, indices[-50:])

# define training and validation data loaders
data_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset,
    batch_size=2,
    shuffle=True,
    num_workers=4,
    collate_fn=collate_fn
)

data_loader_test = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(
    dataset_test,
    batch_size=1,
    shuffle=False,
    num_workers=4,
    collate_fn=collate_fn
)

# get the model using our helper function
model = get_model_instance_segmentation(num_classes)

# move model to the right device
model.to(device)

# construct an optimizer
params = [p for p in model.parameters() if p.requires_grad]
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(
    params,
    lr=0.005,
    momentum=0.9,
    weight_decay=0.0005
)

# and a learning rate scheduler
lr_scheduler = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.StepLR(
    optimizer,
    step_size=3,
    gamma=0.1
)

# let's train it just for 2 epochs
num_epochs = 2

for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # train for one epoch, printing every 10 iterations
    train_one_epoch(model, optimizer, data_loader, device, epoch, print_freq=10)
    # update the learning rate
    lr_scheduler.step()
    # evaluate on the test dataset
    evaluate(model, data_loader_test, device=device)

print("That's it!")
```

At first I thought it might be the conflict between this module with the module of python.So at first I tried to uninstall the python module. It didn't work.

After that I change the name of my file from utils to myutils as you can see in the code. But the error message was the same.

Can anyone give me some thoughts?